# ASP.NET MVC Details view with many display fields but a single editable field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a view that shows a single item with all of its fields.  But I'm getting confused trying to figure out how to allow one specific field ("Status") to be updated from this view, without necessarily going into a whole other "edit" view first.

How do I http-post to the same action (Details) but saving only the "Status" field, without saving all of the other properties which are part of the view model (for display only)?  Do I need a separate view model just for the Status?  New to ASP.NET MVC and getting confused.

### View Model

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Birthdate{ get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
//etc.
```

### View

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Birthdate)
    //etc.
</div>
<div>
    @TextBoxFor(model => model.Status)
    <button type="submit" value="Save Status" />
</div>
```

### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var person = personRepo.GetById(id);
    var vm = BuildPersonDetailsViewModel(person);
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(PersonDetailsViewModel vm)
{
    var person = personRepo.GetById(vm.PersonID);
    person.Status = vm.Status;
    personRepo.Update(person);
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. What problems are you having?

Comment: I was just getting lost between get/post, view models, controller, etc.  I think I figured it out now.  For one thing, I was missing a hidden field storing the person ID (which isn't really needed for a read-only "details" view, but is needed for posting back anything to the database.  I will post more details about my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this by ensuring that the primary key field PersonID is included in the View.  I didn't think I needed it originally because it started off as a read-only Details view, and PersonID wasn't needed to be displayed.  But when posting data back, I needed to add it as a hidden field, so it could be passed to the controller on HttpPost.  Then it can be used to locate and update the record in the database.

Furthermore, I added another method in the repository to allow for updating of just the "Status" field, since that's the only value being updated.  If I use the sample code above, my solution looks something like this:

### View Model

```
public int PersonID { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
//etc.
```

### View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonID)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
//etc. (all the display fields)

@TextBoxFor(model => model.Status)
<button type="submit" value="Save Status" />
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(PersonDetailsViewModel vm)
{
    personRepo.UpdateStatus(vm.PersonID, vm.Status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the case but since i can't tell from the sample code, do you have the `Html.BeginForm(){}` block around the model that you are trying to post? Also maybe try changing the `<button>` tag to `<input type='submit' value='save status'/>` instead

Comment: I do have Html.BeginForm, but I did not have a hidden field for the person ID, which is part of my solution.

Comment: I was going to ask if you were had all of the model's values you wanted to post to the controller in the Razor view but I didn't see an id in the View model you showed.  So is it working now?

Comment: Yes.  Once I started thinking of this as more of an "edit" action/view (although with mainly read-only/display fields and only a single editable field) it started making more sense.  I was coming at it from the wrong angle.